# how can I generate and change random large files to test snapshot performance?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have an attach volume that gets a snapshot every hour.

In order to test the snapshot performance, I need to run a process that will, between snapshot backups, generate a large amount of "churn" or file change.

There are two questions related to this:

1. simply and obviously, how to generate large blocks of text EFFICIENTLY and write them to disc.  With my limited knowledge about the only thing I can think of is a `for` loop generating random characters, but that's probably extremely slow.  Also, the new randomness if replacing a file has to be such that the snapshot essentially has no patterns to match.
2. what is the most effective way to store this?  e.g. 1 Gigabyte in 1000 files, or 100 GB in 10 files

Since a picture is worth 1K words, I drew up this conceptually:

[image]

Thanks in advance for insight on coupling tools-to-use with insight on the file system.

Comment: Related: [What's the fastest way to generate a 1 GB text file containing random digits?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/323845)

Answer (score 0):

> simply and obviously, how to generate large blocks of text EFFICIENTLY and write them to disc. With my limited knowledge about the only thing I can think of is a for loop generating random characters, but that's probably extremely slow.

Why would it be slow? What other way of generating data than running a software loop would exist?

Yeah, a `for` loop is pretty much exactly what you want. Allocate a reasonably sized buffer (512 kB each, for example), fill it with random text (or, really, just bytes, it's not like it makes a difference to your storage medium whether a byte means something specific like "A") and call `write` with that buffer. Move on to the next buffer. Since this is all very linear there's little to be won by being smarter than that – and your CPU is *much* faster at filling  a buffer in RAM than your storage would ever be.

What happens when you call `write` is that the buffer handed in is copied into a file system buffer (in RAM), and `write` returns instantly, so you can generate the next chunk of data. In the meantime, the kernel will start writing that buffer to storage in the background.

This will work fine until the file system buffer is full, and there's no space to immediately copy your data to. Then, your `write` will block until there is space. That's a clever method of always keeping the storage busy and the application working!

So, the first few iterations of your `for`-loop are very fast, but at some point you'll get "throttled" to the average write speed of your storage. Great!

> Also, the new randomness if replacing a file has to be such that the snapshot essentially has no patterns to match.

Use a reasonably fast but not bad PRNG (pseudo-random number generator), anything but libc's `rand` (which is bad, in any way you look at it; **never use `rand`**). I use [xoroshiro128+](https://prng.di.unimi.it/) for pretty high data generation rates.

I benchmarked that once, on my PC, I do ca 0.65 ns per generated pseudo-random 8-byte value, so ca 0.01 ns per random bit, or theoretically 100 Gb/s, single core performance, without even using a SIMD version of xoroshiro128+. Chances are  that's orders of magnitude faster than your storage interfaces probably are (unless you're forgetting to tell us you work at Google, Cloudflare, LHC or the NSA).

> what is the most effective way to store this? e.g. 1 Gigabyte in 1000 files, or 100 GB in 10 file

Doesn't really matter, 1000 files are not many, and the overhead is negligible. Still, the least-overhead variant would be 1 file of 1 TB.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that I have developed that works:

```bsh
# init
__PWD__=$(pwd)
cd $(dirname $0)
__THIS_FILE__=$0
__THIS_DIR__=$(pwd)
write_loc='/../create-large-files-repository/'
__TARGET_DIR__="$__THIS_DIR__$write_loc"
cd $__PWD__

# output
echo running script: $__THIS_FILE__
echo current directory: $__THIS_DIR__
echo files written to: $__TARGET_DIR__

if [[ ! -d $__TARGET_DIR__ ]]; then mkdir $__TARGET_DIR__; fi

FILE_COUNT=100
FILE_SIZE=1000000

for ((i = 0 ; i < $FILE_COUNT ; i++)); do
  file="file$i.dta"
  file="$__TARGET_DIR__$file"
  echo processing $file..
  dd if=/dev/urandom of=$file bs=2048 count=$FILE_SIZE
done
```

This is running at about 30s per Gigabyte, so at 2GB per minute one could conceivably get about .12TB in an hour.  The actual goal would be to generate >1TB in an hour so I will update this with system load when running ~10 of these in parallel.  `/dev/urandom/` is not blocking so this seems (for the moment) to be performant.